# View is not child error in ChildHelper.java when dragging/dropping list items in RecyclerView using ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback to add drag and drop functionality to my RecyclerView, however it will randomly crash after dragging items around. Sometimes it will happen after the first fews times I drag an item around, however sometimes I will sit there for minutes just moving items around to try to reproduce it with no luck. The list item layout xml uses a ConstraintLayout as the root view. The RecyclerView is in a fragment that I navigate to with a TabLayout. I have tried looking up the error but can't find much info on it.

Here is the Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ferox.bracket, PID: 12379
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: view is not a child, cannot hide android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout{45c7cc V.E...... ......ID 0,-231-1080,-81 #7f0900a8 app:id/participant_parent_layout}
        at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.unhide(ChildHelper.java:352)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getScrapOrHiddenOrCachedHolderForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6393)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5896)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557) 
        at ...
```

My ItemTouchHelper:

```
this.helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper
.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.START) {

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, 
        @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, 
        @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

    int movedPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    int targetPostition = target.getAdapterPosition();

    swapSeed(players.get(movedPosition), players.get(targetPostition));
    Collections.swap(players, movedPosition, targetPostition);

    notifyItemMoved(movedPosition, targetPostition);
    notifyItemChanged(targetPostition);
    notifyItemChanged(movedPosition);

    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

    new AlertDialog.Builder(viewHolder.itemView.getContext()).setMessage("Delete participant?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
                players.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, which) -> {
                defaultItemAnimator.setSupportsChangeAnimations(true);
                notifyItemChanged(position, null);
            })
            .create().show();
    }


    @Override
    public float getSwipeThreshold(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    return .7f;
    }

    @Override
    public float getSwipeEscapeVelocity(float defaultValue) {
    return super.getSwipeEscapeVelocity(5f * defaultValue);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
    return false;
    }
```

});

My Fragment's OnCreate:

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_participants, container, false);
    CustomLinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);

    DefaultItemAnimator defaultItemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
    defaultItemAnimator.setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), players, linearLayoutManager, defaultItemAnimator);

    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.participant_list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(defaultItemAnimator);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.getHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    url = intent.getStringExtra("tournamentURL");
    ChallongeRequests.sendGet(response -> initPlayerList(response), ChallongeRequests.participantIndex(url));
    return v;
}
```

EDIT:It seems to happen only after scrolling some undetermined amount while simultaneously dragging a viewholder. I've set DefaultItemAnimator.setSupportsChangeAnimations() to false and I've stopped  getting the error.However this creates another issue where upon hitting "No" when asked to remove a list item after a swipe, notifyItemChanged does not slide the view back into place. I can work around this by setting setSupportsChangeAnimations() on and off in my code as needed, but I feel as if the default behavior of the recyclerview shouldn't be causing this error. I'm not sure if theres something I should be doing with the itemanimator that I haven't done or what.